# Any way to send / receive iMessages from / to email?

Tags: iphone, email, messages

I get and send a lot of iMessages every day, but I find it inconvenient to use my iPhone (with its small screen).

I was wondering if there was any way to have iMessages be sent as email threads to an email address so that I could easily view them from a computer?

Also, is there a way to do the opposite: to reply to that email thread, which would send a message in iMessage?

I've heard complaints about this (messages sending via email) as a negative thing, but I would like to use it to my advantage.

Comment: iMessage works just fine on a Mac. Do you use a PC?

Comment: @bjbk Sorry, I forgot to mention that I use Ubuntu and Windows (so yes, a PC).